# Problem with abortMultiPart using S3 mock findify

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to cancel a multiPartUpload that won't be completed, I'm making the request to initiate the upload with the following code

```
      CreateMultipartUploadRequest request = CreateMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
     .bucket(bucket).key(destinationUrl).build();
  CreateMultipartUploadResponse multipart = s3Client.createMultipartUpload(request);
  return multipart.uploadId();
```

The CreateMultipartUploadResponse has the three values, bucket, key and uploadId
I'm passing the same 3 values to cancel the upload and it returns 404 not found

```
  var abortUploadRequest = AbortMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
  .uploadId(uploadId)
  .bucket(bucket)
  .key(key)
  .build();
  s3Client.abortMultipartUpload(abortUploadRequest);
```

any idea why? the upload of the file works fine

Comment: 404 suggest that the Multipart isn't located. Could that be due to authentication parameters? Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_AbortMultipartUpload.html#API_AbortMultipartUpload_Errors

Comment: Could you share the response body associated with the 404 NOT_FOUND request/response of the AbortUploadRequest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you initiate the real upload after creating the MultiPartUploadRequest ?

According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/abort-mpu.html) :

> After you initiate a multipart upload, you begin uploading parts. Amazon S3 stores these parts, but it creates the object from the parts only after you upload all of them and send a successful request to complete the multipart upload (you should verify that your request to complete multipart upload is successful).

> You can stop an in-progress multipart upload in Amazon S3 using the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI), REST API, or AWS SDKs. You can also stop an incomplete multipart upload using a bucket lifecycle configuration.

So if you only created the MultiPartUploadRequest but didnt really upload parts using the UploadPart function, it should be normal that the S3 client returns 404 on the abort since nothing is associated with the UploadId.

Also see this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html) should help.

Comment: This helped me, thats true I initiated the upload but didn't upload any part, I'm gonna try uploading one part but I'm sure will be this, thanks!

Comment: sadly it didnt work, i have 5 parts uploaded and still returns a 404

Comment: Could you share both request / responses from `MultiPartUploadRequest` and `AbortMultipartUploadRequest` ?